# Get Open Windows in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos

How would I get the names of the open windows on Mac OSX in Objective C? Basically I just want to check if a window with a specific name (ie. "Chrome" to detect if Chrome is open) is open.

The app in question will NEVER run without a window open (unlike Chrome in my example), so detecting running *processes* may not be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case you describe, looking through the window list is not a good approach. For example, Chrome does not have a window named "Chrome" AFAIK — the names of its windows depend on the currently open tab. If you want to detect an application, use NSWorkSpace's [launchedApplications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/launchedApplications) method.

To actually detect windows, use the [Quartz Window Services API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html).

Comment: Sorry, Chrome was not a good example. The application I want to detect is always going to be named one thing and will always have a window open if the process is running. I'll look at the Quartz Window Services/NSWorkspace.

Comment: My 2 cents: (update): It is strongly suggested that you use the NSWorkspaceclass’s runningApplications method and the NSRunningApplication class to retrieve this information in applications targeted to OS X v10.6 and later, rather than the activeApplication and launchedApplications methods.